# JS function name appears on asp.net content page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

This is an odd problem that I can't seem to even find a good way to Google for an answer.

I have an asp.net web forms site that uses master/content pages. On one page a javascript function is at the top called "rePrintPrompt". When i run the site, using localhost for testing the javascript function name appears just above the asp panels.

[image]

I can't find it anywhere in the code that is displaying the function name.

Here is the aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/SiteMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Reports.aspx.vb" Inherits="Reports" %>


 <%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
        <link href="SiteStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/fav_icon_OGI_Logo.PNG" type="image/x-icon" />
<%-- Javascript to check reprint function --%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function rePrintPrompt()
    {
        var answer = prompt("Is this a reprint job? Y/N", "N")
        if (answer == null || answer == "")
        {
            answer = prompt("Is this a reprint job? Y/N", "N")
        } else if(answer == "Y")
        {
            var answer2 = prompt("Please enter Order #, Mark #, and Qty:")
            if (answer2 == nul || answer2 == "")
            {
                answer2 = prompt("Please enter Order #, Mark #, and Qty:")
            } else
            {
                var answers = str.split(",")
                document.getElementById('<%= hOrderNumber.ClientID %>').value = answers[0]
                document.getElementById('<%= hMarkNumber.ClientID %>').value = answers[1]
                document.getElementById('<%= hQty.ClientID %>').value = answers[2]
                document.getElementById('<%= hRePrint.ClientID %>').value = "Y"
                document.getElementById('<%= btnPieceLabels.ClientID %>').click()
            }
        }
    }
</script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MasterContentLeft" Runat="Server">
    <div id="RptOptBtn">
        <asp:Button ID="btnBanding" runat="server" CssClass="DCLButton" Text="Banding Rpt" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnBearingBar" runat="server" CssClass="DCLButton" Text="Bearing Bar Rpt" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCrossBar" runat="server" CssClass="DCLButton" Text="Cross Bar Rpt" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnPackingList" runat="server" CssClass="DCLButton" Text="Packing List Rpt" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnBatchLabels" runat="server" CssClass="DCLButton" Text="Batch Labels" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnPieceLabels" runat="server" CssClass="DCLButton" Text="Piece Labels" OnClientClick="rePrintPrompt();" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" CssClass="DCLButton" Text="Close" />
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hLabelType" />
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hOrderNumber" />
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hMarkNumber" />
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hQty" />
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hRePrint" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MasterContentRight" Runat="Server">
    <div id="RptPanels">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlBandingRpt" runat="server" Width="990px" Visible="false">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvBanding" runat="server" BackColor="White" Width="990px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" AsyncRendering="False" ShowBackButton="False" ShowCredentialPrompts="False" ShowDocumentMapButton="False" ShowExportControls="False" ShowFindControls="False" ShowParameterPrompts="False" ShowPromptAreaButton="False" ShowRefreshButton="False" ShowZoomControl="False" SizeToReportContent="True">
                <ServerReport ReportPath="/OGI Department Folders/Production/Banding" ReportServerUrl="http://sql4/ReportServer_SQL4" />
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlPackingList" runat="server" Width="990px" Visible="false">
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvPackingList" runat="server" BackColor="White" Width="990px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" AsyncRendering="False" ShowBackButton="False" ShowCredentialPrompts="False" ShowDocumentMapButton="False" ShowExportControls="False" ShowFindControls="False" ShowParameterPrompts="False" ShowPromptAreaButton="False" ShowRefreshButton="False" ShowZoomControl="False" SizeToReportContent="True">
                <ServerReport ReportPath="/OGI Department Folders/Production/PackingList" ReportServerUrl="http://sql4/ReportServer_SQL4" />
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlCrossBarRpt" runat="server" Width="990px" Visible="false">
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvCrossBar" runat="server" BackColor="White" Width="990px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" AsyncRendering="False" ShowBackButton="False" ShowCredentialPrompts="False" ShowDocumentMapButton="False" ShowExportControls="False" ShowFindControls="False" ShowParameterPrompts="False" ShowPromptAreaButton="False" ShowRefreshButton="False" ShowZoomControl="False" SizeToReportContent="True">
                <ServerReport ReportPath="/OGI Department Folders/Production/CrossBarRpt" ReportServerUrl="http://sql4/ReportServer_SQL4" />
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlBearingBarRpt" runat="server" Width="990px" Visible="false">
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvBearingBar" runat="server" BackColor="White" Width="990px"  Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" AsyncRendering="False" ShowBackButton="False" ShowCredentialPrompts="False" ShowDocumentMapButton="False" ShowExportControls="False" ShowFindControls="False" ShowParameterPrompts="False" ShowPromptAreaButton="False" ShowRefreshButton="False" ShowZoomControl="False" SizeToReportContent="True">
                <ServerReport ReportPath="/OGI Department Folders/Production/BearingbarRpt" ReportServerUrl="http://sql4/ReportServer_SQL4" />
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlBatchLabels" runat="server" Width="990px" Visible="false">
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvBatchLabels" runat="server" BackColor="White" Width="990px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" AsyncRendering="False" ShowBackButton="False" ShowCredentialPrompts="False" ShowDocumentMapButton="False" ShowExportControls="False" ShowFindControls="False" ShowParameterPrompts="False" ShowPromptAreaButton="False" ShowRefreshButton="False" ShowZoomControl="False" SizeToReportContent="True">
                <ServerReport ReportPath="/OGI Department Folders/Production/BatchLabel" ReportServerUrl="http://sql4/ReportServer_SQL4" />
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlPieceLabels" runat="server" Width="990px" Visible="false">
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvPieceLabels" runat="server" BackColor="White" Width="990px"  Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" AsyncRendering="False" ShowBackButton="False" ShowCredentialPrompts="False" ShowDocumentMapButton="False" ShowExportControls="False" ShowFindControls="False" ShowParameterPrompts="False" ShowPromptAreaButton="False" ShowRefreshButton="False" ShowZoomControl="False" SizeToReportContent="True">
                <ServerReport ReportPath="/OGI Department Folders/Production/PieceLabels" ReportServerUrl="http://sql4/ReportServer_SQL4" />
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Why would the name be displayed? I have never had this happen before.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: In the code behind this is the only place the function is referenced:

```
    Private Sub Reports_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Get passed order number
    oNumber = Request.QueryString("ordernum").ToString()
    btnPieceLabels.Attributes.Add("onclick", "rePrintPrompt")
    If Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("rePrintPrompt") AndAlso Not IsPostBack Then
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](), "rPrintLabels", "rePrintPrompt")
    End If
```

After checking the page with browser developer tools I found this:

[image]

I do not know why it would be adding this to the page.

Comment: i didn’t see the full code above your js, where the first <asp:content> starts?

Comment: The first thing I would try is removing the comment above the JavaScript.  If you want to leave a comment in HTML, it should be using <!-- bla bla -->

Comment: Removed it, really wasn't needed, but made no difference.

Comment: No movement of this? I still cannot figure out why this is happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after many months of messing with this problem I finally figured out where the problem is coming from.

In the code behind file for the page load I have a Client Register Script line:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](), "cqar", "closeqar")
```

The last segment that has closeqar in double quotes is where the rogue text is coming from. I simply changed it to "" and the text disappeared. So the line now reads:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](), "cqar", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't need the `RegisterClientScriptBlock` at all. Your script is already on the page. `RegisterClientScriptBlock` is used to add new script to the page. All you need is the `Attributes.Add` part.

```
btnPieceLabels.Attributes.Add("onclick", "rePrintPrompt")
// If Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("rePrintPrompt") AndAlso Not IsPostBack Then
//    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](), "rPrintLabels", "rePrintPrompt")
// End If
```

(I'm not sure if comments in vb.net are double-slashes or ticks.)

Edit: I just noticed that you also already have an OnClientClick on your button, so you shouldn't need `btnPieceLabels.Attributes.Add` either.